# how can i perform an update and get in the same query to use in a foreach?

Tags: laravel

how can i get data from query $ or while updating it?
wanted to run a foreach to send an email when the update was done

```
$x = encomendas::where('estado', 3)->where('updated_at', '<', $dias2)
            ->join('distritos', 'encomendas.distrito', '=', 'distritos.id')
            ->update(['estado' => 4])->get();

foreach ($encomendasnaopagas as $email) {
            Mail::send('emails.cliente.cancelada', [
                'id_encomenda' => $email->id,
          

            ], function ($messagem) use ($email) {

                $messagem->from('noreply@cccc.pt', 'xxx');

                $messagem->to($email->email)->subject('xxxxx');
            });
        }
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same object which you used for update operation.

```
$encomendasnaopagas = encomendas::where('estado', 3)->where('updated_at', '<', $dias2)
            ->join('distritos', 'encomendas.distrito', '=', 'distritos.id')
            ->get();
foreach ($encomendasnaopagas as $value) {
    if( $value->update($arrayyouwanttoUpdate)){
          // if update is done successfully update() will return true, use that in your if condition
          // now use $value to send emails
    }

}
```